# Using wget to recursively download whole FTP directories

Tags: ftp, recursive

I want to copy all of the files and folders from one host to another.
The files on the old host sit at /var/www/html and I only have FTP access to that server, and I can't TAR all the files.
Regular connection to the old host through FTP brings me to the /home/admin folder.

I tried running the following command form my new server:

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host
```

But all I get is a made up index.html file.

What the right syntax for using wget recursively over FTP?

Comment: Note that, by default, wget -r has a maximum recursion depth of 5; if you have an deeper subdirectories, they will be ignored unless you change this (see -l in the man page).

Comment: What wget does also depends on wget version (or build) I came across one _GNU Wget 1.10.2 (Red Hat modified)_ where when path ends without '/' wget considers it a file and a download fails, but when `--timestamping` (-N) is used, it would work. Then when path ended in '/' it would always create an index.html instead of downloading files. Ending in * would also work for a dir. In all cases also `--recursive` was used.

Answer (score 156):

Try `-m` for `--mirror`

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host
```

Comment: For security reason, it would be good to use `--ask-password` to avoid password being kept in `history`.

Comment: This is so cool. Worked like a charm..

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (for better visibility).

Comment: it doesn't include path of directory to download, I guess @Formoda answer is better

Comment: @WasimA., you can just add directory path here as well: `wget -m ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host/mydir/`

Answer (score 48):

You have it right, you just need a trailing * on the end:

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@1.2.3.4/dir/*
```

For shared servers, you can use like this:

```
wget -r ftp://1.2.3.4/dir/* --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password
```

Because most shared servers has ftp-username something like username@hostname, so, the first wget command not works, and second command works fine.

Comment: This would only go one directory deep.Better to use the -m flag

Comment: in some cases second command is not working because of space, You can use first command for share hosting like this. ** wget -r ftp:/ /username%40host:password@host/dir/ **

Comment: Note: you should use either `-m` or  `-r -l inf` because -r has a default recursion depth of 5. See https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options

Answer (score 11):

Check the below wget command to download data from FTP recursively.

```
wget --user="<user-name>" --password="<password>" -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=1 --reject "index.html*" "<URL to download files>"
```

`-r`: Is for recursively download.

`-np`: Is for no parent ascending.

`-nH`: Is for disabling creation of directory having name same as URL i.e. abc.xyz.com

`--cut-dirs`: Is for ignoring number of parent directories. The value of this option will differ for your command.

You can check by executing the above command.

Comment: What does the --reject do?  Is there any way to specify that it is not to overwrite anything?

Answer (score 8):

Besides wget, you may also use **lftp** in script mode. The following command will mirror the content of a given remote FTP directory into the given local directory, and it can be put into the cron job:

```
lftp -c 'open <hostname>; user <username> <password>; mirror -e <remote-src-path> <local-dest-path>; quit'
```

It automatically handles recursion into directories and allows specifying the remote source starting directory from to download data from.

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'curlftpfs - mount a ftp host as a local directory' and, once mounted, you can use normal file tools like 'cp -r'.

Comment: `curlftpfs` has major performance problems right now unless you downgrade `libcurl3-gnutls`

Answer (score 4):

Should work try:

```
wget -r ftp://ftp:ftp@ftp.sunet.se/tst/
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
wget -m ftp://192.168.0.1
```

and it will mirror all the files and folders.

Comment: As I said, logging in through FTP takes me to the /home/admin folder, and the files I need are in /var/www/html
So when I run the command you suggested, I only get the contents of /home/admin
I tried running it with ftp://192.168.0.1/var/www/html, but then it tries to CWD /home/admin/var/www/html. How do I make it go to this folder from the root?

Comment: I have no experience with this particular problem, but you could try making a symlink to /var/www/html under your home. Then you could use an address like ftp://192.168.0.1/html

Comment: I tried creating a symlink, but it resulted with wget creating a similar symlink on my local.

Answer (score 3):

Use -m rather than -r, because of the recursion depth.

http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_2.html#SEC11

Answer (score 1):

That's the right syntax. Not sure why you aren't getting the expected results.

As ever there is more than one way to do it. Try ncftp, in particular ncftpget

Comment: I can't install more software on my new server.
Shouldn't I be telling wget to download all files from /var/www/html? I tried wget -r ftp://username:password@ip.of.old.host/var/www/html but I got a directory not found error.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand if you're trying to dump this into cron or something, but why not simply ftp into the server with your normal client and mget *? This might be a quicker path to success.

Comment: I tried mget * but it didn't work with sub-folders, saying the local sub-folder doesn't exist. Is there a way to make him create the local folders automatically?

Comment: Depending on your client, the -r switch usually does the trick. IE:

mget -r *

Comment: mmm. AFAIK standard ftp client in linux is not designed to retrieve directories recursively. I mean - there is no -r option. other clients like ncftp or lftp support recursive retrieval but they usually not available by default.

Answer (score 1):

> As I said, logging in through FTP
>   takes me to the /home/admin folder,
>   and the files I need are in
>   /var/www/html

I think this will work in your case:

```
wget -r ftp://192.168.0.1/../../var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across Windows hosting with the username as brinkster/username, so wget would throw an error if you use the syntax:

```
wget -m ftp://brinkster/username:password@ip.of.the.host
```

To get past this, use

```
wget -m ftp://brinkster%2Fusername:password@ip.of.old.host
```

I had to face this with Windows hosting @ brinkster.

Answer (score -3):

`wget --user username --password yourpassword ftp://example.com/ftpfiles/filename` will do the job or you can add * instead of filename entring : makes wget think of port which is invalid in your case.

Comment: This answer to a four year old question with multiple upvoted answers doesn't offer anything new and even omits the requirement for a recursive copy.